# How to move image view from left to right in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to make a custom switch button with an image view that moves to the right of its container when clicked and to the left of the container when clicked again. What code do I need for this?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

internal class container : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var shape: UIImageView!


override internal func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
}



@IBAction func shapeMove(sender: AnyObject) {

}
}
```

shape is the image view that should be moved left to right.

Comment: Use this, inside the @IBAction function: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a bool variable for maintaining the state.

```
var isImageLeftSide = true

@IBAction func shapeMove(sender: AnyObject) {
    var customFrame = shape.frame
    if isImageLeftSide {
         customFrame.origin.x = customFrame.origin.x + 25   //assuming 25 is pixels by which your image should be shifted
    }
    else {
         customFrame.origin.x = customFrame.origin.x - 25
    }
    shape.frame = customFrame
    isImageLeftSide = ! isImageLeftSide
}
```

Next all you have to do this check the state and change x coordinate of your shape view. If it is to left side increase the x coordinate and if it is to right side decrease x coordinate